# React Native Web error with react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, webpack, react-native-vector-icons

I am making an app with react-native and react-native-web. I have tried to add react-native-vector-icons to the project follow this [documentation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) and i got an error on the web build:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js 91:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (91:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|       return (
>         <Text selectable={false} {...props}>
|           {glyph}
|           {children}
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome.js 6:0-50 9:16-29
 @ ./src/App.js 1:1549-1597
 @ ./index.web.js 1:261-281
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(js)|(jsx)$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: [
        'react-native-web',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
}

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = {
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.html'),
}

const copyWebpackPluginConfig = {
  patterns: [
    {
      from: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'assets/fonts/'),
      to: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'public/assets/fonts'),
      noErrorOnMissing: true,
    },
    {
      from: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'assets/images/'),
      to: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'public/assets/images'),
      noErrorOnMissing: true,
    },
  ],
}

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
    },
  },
}

const iconFontLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  loader: 'url-loader', // or directly file-loader
  include: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
}

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js')],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[contenthash].web.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'public'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoaderConfiguration,
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      iconFontLoaderConfiguration,
    ],
  },

  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(HtmlWebpackPluginConfig),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(copyWebpackPluginConfig),
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      '@api': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/api/'),
      '@entities': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/entities/'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/utils/'),
      '@components': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/components/'),
      '@theme': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/theme/'),
      '@constants': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/constants/'),
      '@screens': path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src/screens'),
    },

    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
}
```

I also have tried to change url-loader to file-loader and ttf-loader an i got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just faced exactly the same trouble, I've solved by adding these two rules in the `webpack.config.js` file

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(react-native-elements|react-native-vector-icons)\/).*/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native-vector-icons")
      }
  ]
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack.config.js file paste the below code

```
   module: {          
                {
                  test: /\.ttf$/,
                  loader: 'url-loader', // or directly file-loader
                  include: path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons',
                  ),
                },
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added these lines on top of `index.web.js` to inject fontFace into web styles. I wanted to add `AntDesign`:

```
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf';
const AntDesignStyles = `@font-face {
  src: url(${AntDesign});
  font-family: AntDesign;
}`;

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';

if (style.styleSheet) {
   style.styleSheet.cssText = AntDesignStyles;
} else {
   style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(AntDesignStyles));
}

document.head.appendChild(style);
```

I've added these two rules to `webpack.config.js` that [@CrsCaballero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955448/8191659) mentioned in his reply:

```
...
module: {
rules: [
...
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(react-native-elements|react-native-vector-icons)\/).*/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native-vector-icons")
  }
]
}
...
```